# VBA ListRows.Add not only adds the row but adds data at the same time. can't figure out why

Tags: excel, vba

I'm VBA self-taught and my work figured that out and now wants me to start VBA coding for them. I have come across 2 problems in my code that I don't know how to fix. The first problem is when the line of code 'Set NewAnalyte = Table.ListRows.Add' is run, it doesn't just add a row, it adds a row with data from my Master Sheet to a new page. i just want a blank new row that has no information until the With statements run.

The second problem is that on further iterations, all previous rows are overwritten with the newest row's data. So let's say I had 15 Lipoic Acid samples from my 'Master Sheet' that were moved over to my 'Lipoic Acid' sheet. All 15 entries have identical data that is identical to whatever the last entry is.

First post on Stackoverflow, so if something is wrong/poor form with my post/problem presentation, please let me know for future posts. Thanks.

```
Dim AnalyteName          As Range
Dim Cell                 As Range
Dim WS                   As Worksheet
Dim NewAnalyte           As ListRow
Dim Table                As ListObject
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Set AnalyteName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Sheet").Range("B3:B100")

For Each Cell In AnalyteName
    If (InStr(1, Cell.Value, "Lipoic Acid") > 0) Then
        Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lipoic Acid")
        Set Table = WS.ListObjects("LipoicAcid")
        Set NewAnalyte = Table.ListRows.Add
            With NewAnalyte
                 .Range(1) = "='Master Sheet'!" + Cell.Offset(0, -1).Address
                 .Range(2) = "='Master Sheet'!" + Cell.Offset(0, 1).Address
                 .Range(3) = "='Master Sheet'!" + Cell.Offset(0, 5).Address
                 .Range(4) = "='Master Sheet'!" + Cell.Offset(0, 2).Address
                 .Range(5) = "='Master Sheet'!" + Cell.Offset(0, 6).Address
                 .Range(6) = "='Master Sheet'!" + Cell.Offset(0, 3).Address
            End With
```

Comment: If you step through your code using the F8 key, you'll see that when `Set NewAnalyte = Table.ListRows.Add` is executed that it adds only a blank row.  The data is added the `With/End With` statement is executed.

Comment: Yeah I did a Step Through, and that is why I was super confused because the data gets entered the same time as the line is added. and then the With/End With overrides that data. No idea where the data is coming from. I had never seen that before. I actually inherited the table from a different user, could it be built into the table itself?

Comment: It looks like you probably have formulas in your table.  If so, those formulas would be replicated in the newly added row.

Comment: You can prevent this from happening by setting AutoFillFormulasInLists to False before adding the row -- `Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False` -- and then setting back to True once you're done.